# Can you create a time spin-control with R gWidgets?

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

Can I create a time spin-control like the one shown below with R gWidgets?

[image]

I tried creating my own:

```
w <- gwindow(height = 30)
glabel(container = w, "H:")
analysisTimeStartH <- gspinbutton(container = w, from = 0, to = 23, by = 1)
glabel(container = w, "M:")
analysisTimeStartM <- gspinbutton(container = w, from = 0, to = 59, by = 1)
glabel(container = w, "S:")
analysisTimeInterval <- gspinbutton(container = w, from = 0, to = 59, by = 1)
```

[image]

but the outcome is unsatisfactory: for instance, when the time displayed is 23:59:59, I want the next increment to roll over to 00:00:00. However, the spin controls do not take into consideration the modulo arithmetic required when dealing with time and does not allow me to increment further (notice the increase increment button is disabled in the screenshot).

So is there a native time spin-control offered by gWidgets?

For reference, my system details are:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is an underlying assumption that the values to select from are numeric. This isn't necessary with tcltk, but seems to be for Gtk, so likely won't be changed. Your approach can be made to work. Here is a bit more on your approach that enforces some limits:

```
library(gWidgets2)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")

TimeSpinner <- setRefClass("TimeSpinner",
                           fields=c("hour", "minute", "second"),
                           methods=list(
                               initialize = function(container, h=0, m=0, s=0, ...) {
                                   g <- ggroup(cont=container)
                                   hour <<- gspinbutton(from=0, to=23, by=1, value=h, cont=g)
                                   minute <<- gspinbutton(from=-1, to=60, by=1, value=m, cont=g)
                                   second <<- gspinbutton(from=-1, to=60, by=1, value=s, cont=g)
                                   add_handlers()
                                   callSuper(...)
                               },
                               get_value=function() {
                                   list(hour=svalue(hour), minute=svalue(minute), second=svalue(second))
                               },
                               set_value=function(h,m,s) {
                                   hour$set_value(h)
                                   minute$set_value(m)
                                   second$set_value(s)
                               },
                               add_handlers=function() {
                                   addHandlerChanged(hour, function (h,...) {
                                       val <- svalue(hour)
                                       if (val < 0)
                                           hour$set_value(0)
                                       else if (val > 23)
                                           hour$set_value(23)
                                   })
                                   addHandlerChanged(minute, function(h,...) {
                                       val <- svalue(minute)
                                       if (val == -1) {
                                           minute$set_value(59)
                                           hour$set_value(svalue(hour) - 1)
                                       } else if(val == 60) {
                                           minute$set_value(0)
                                           hour$set_value(svalue(hour) + 1)
                                       }
                                   })
                                    addHandlerChanged(second, function(h,...) {
                                       val <- svalue(second)
                                       if (val == -1) {
                                           second$set_value(59)
                                           minute$set_value(svalue(hour) - 1)
                                       } else if(val == 60) {
                                           second$set_value(0)
                                           minute$set_value(svalue(hour) + 1)
                                       }
                                   })
                               }
                           ))

w <- gwindow()
ts <- TimeSpinner$new(w)
```